# How to link checkbox with contactList in android?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, contacts

I want to show Contact list with multiselection Check-box in android.How can I achieve this.
Can any one suggest any example or code then it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer.....

```
public class ShowContactActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> listname;
    ArrayList<String> list_no;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ListView lView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show);

        lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_no = new ArrayList<String>();


        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        String name = cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {


            Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
                    new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    // Do something with phones
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    listname.add(name); // Here I collect the name of contact person and phone number. 
                    list_no.add(phoneNo);

                    } 
                    pCur.close();           
            }
         }      

       }
        lView.setAdapter(new Contact(this));                
    }

    class Contact extends BaseAdapter
    {
        Context myContext;      

        public Contact(ShowContactActivity contactActivity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.myContext = contactActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return listname.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (convertView == null) {

                inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.text_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);   

                viewHolder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }

            final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            holder.text_name.setText(list_no.get(position));
            holder.id.setText(listname.get(position));


            if(holder != null)
            {
                holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Here We can do our rest of stuff             
                        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Selected item is :-"  +buttonView.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            return convertView;              
        }       
    }    
    class ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView text_name,id;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        //EditText search;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own contact list.

follow [this link](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/) to fetch contacts and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) to customize listview.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the replay.I got some what idea from your comment.